# Relationship between Table, Rowset and Rows in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm working on a project that requires a fair bit of inserting/updating rows in MySQL tables using Zend_Form. I'm trying to simplify the insert/update procedure by extending Zend_Db, and it seems a lot of this has been done with Zend_Db_Table and Zend_Db_Table_Row.

However, I can't understand how to link them together in the most efficient way. For example, I have a DB table called **companies**. I then have a model called **CompaniesTable** that extends `Zend_Db_Table` and a model called **CompanyTable** that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Row`.

I want to be able to query the **companies** table for rows, insert/update/delete individual companies etc. I see a few sites referring to the DomainModel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) but can't find a good explanation of how to do it in Zend Framework.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial?

Cheers,
   Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.survivethedeepend.com/ is the site for a free online book about best practices using ZF, being written by Pádraic Brady, a long-time ZF contributor.

Especially read [Chapter 3, The Model](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/the.model), and [Chapter 9, Implementing the Domain Model](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors).

Comment: Actually, do you know of any sites that explain how to call the data access model (on the above site, called the "Mapper") from the domain object model? It seems he hasn't got around to writing that chapter yet, and it's not clear what the best practice is for accessing the data mapper from the main model